# Garbage when loading xml content with URLConnection

Tags: java, xml, web-crawler

I'm trying to load the content of an `XML` page using `URLConnection` but I'm getting back garbage characters. The same code works for me for pretty much any other site so I'm not sure what's the issue.

Here's the relevant code:

```
String url = "http://myUrl";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(60*2000); // wait only 60 seconds for a response
conn.setReadTimeout(60*2000);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), encoding);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    wholeDocument += inputLine;     
}
```

Printing out `wholeDocument` produces a bunch of characters like this: `er���;�pI.���$6`

I am using `encoding = 'UTF-8'`.

I also tried using `XML` libraries, for example:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new URL(baseUrl).openStream());
System.out.println("doc = " + doc);
```

But the result is the same. When using `curl` in a terminal app (I'm on a `mac`) the result is similar although the characters look like this: `???0??KZV??????0N6?aH:$?X9v??`?$>???`

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the headers of your response you will see **Content-Encoding: gzip** indicating that the body of the response has been compressed, you need to uncompress it first, that's why you get those weird characters. More details about [Http Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

A good way to check the headers with `curl` is to use the verbose option `-v`, In this case thanks to `curl -v http://sites.one.co.il/XML/VOD/ | more`, I could quickly see the response headers.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the other answer, you can check if the received file is gzip encoded, and decode it if so by:

```java
 if (conn.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding") != null && 
        conn.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding").equals("gzip")){
    InputStream gzStream = new GZIPInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(gzStream, encoding);
} else {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), encoding);
}
```

Alternatively, you can specify that you wouldn't like gzip encoded data by:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```